# Thermal printer web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to print shippig labels on my thermal printer. I have a web application 
Using vb.net. Is there any standard solution for this? If its not possible to print using web application then i can migrate to windows application as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest thing to do is to have you web application create a pdf, and then serve up / return that pdf to the user - who can then use standard print dialog to send your perfectly formatted results to the printer using the drivers installed.

Comment: Not a bad idea, however what should be the dimensions for pdf... And could i avoid windows print dialoge in my app? Or print them in batch?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use an java applet

jzebra
Free browser applet for sending raw commands to your printer
http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/

Comment: @highwingers  if you built an ActiveX control, possibly, but how much would you alienate yourself on Firefox, Safari, etc.?